# How to programmatically restart network account server on Mac?

Tags: linux, networking, macos

In Mac -> System Preference -> Users & Groups -> Login Options:

At the bottom there is a "Network Account Server" option, I have a few servers running. But occasionally it appears to be red because some servers did not connect correctly. What I used to do is to remove that server and re-add it so it connects again.

I wonder if I can do this programmatically via shell script. i.e. restart all network account server or remove and re-add the server URL. I am not very familiar with how FreeBSD manages these network settings. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on exactly what's gone wrong with the connections, and what kind they are (Active Directory, Open Directory, generic LDAP, NIS, or something else?). If it's just some sort of transient glitch, you may be able to un-glitch it by restarting the daemon that handles the directory service connections. It's named "opendirectoryd" in recent versions (so you'd reset it with `sudo killall opendirectoryd`), but was called "DirectoryService" in earlier versions.

If there's a more persistent problem, it'd be best to try to figure out what's going wrong and solve it properly. But if necessary you can unbind and rebind at the command line with [`dsconfigladp`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dsconfigldap.1.html) (for Open Directory and generic LDAP), and [`dsconfigad`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/dsconfigad.8.html) (for Active Directory).